# How to pass a value from one UIViewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an app where I have to pass a value from a `second class` to a `first class`.  I have created a delegate method for that in `second class`.

In `second class` I have a `UITextField`, and if enter any text in this textfield it should be passed to a `cell` in a `UITableView` in `first view`.

However, in my case the value is not being passed properly. What have I done wrong?

This is my code:

**second.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol secondDelegate<NSObject>
@required
- (void)setsecond:(NSString *)inputString;
@end

@interface second : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *secondtextfield;
    id<secondDelegate>stringdelegate;
    NSString *favoriteColorString; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *secondtextfield;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<secondDelegate>stringdelegate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *favoriteColorString;
@end
```

**second.m**

```
#import "second.h"

@implementation second
@synthesize stringdelegate, secondtextfield, favoriteColorString;

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[self stringdelegate] setsecond:secondtextfield.text];
    favoriteColorString=secondtextfield.text;
    NSLog(@"thuis check:%@", favoriteColorString);
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[[self stringdelegate] setsecond:secondtextfield.text];
    //favoriteColorString = secondtextfield.text;
    //NSLog(@"thuis check:%@", favoriteColorString);
}
@end
```

**first.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "second.h"
#import "TextviewExampleAppDelegate.h"

@interface first : UITableViewController<secondDelegate> {
    //TextviewExampleAppDelegate *app;
    TextviewExampleAppDelegate *check;
}
```

**first.m**

```
@implementation first

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"message";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = check.favoriteColorString;
    NSLog(@"this second check:%@", check.favoriteColorString);
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    second *viewtwo = [[second alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
    //viewtwo.favoriteColorString = indexPath;
    viewtwo.stringdelegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewtwo animated:YES];
    [viewtwo release];
}

- (void)setsecond:(NSString *)inputString { 
    if (nil != self.stringdelegate) {
        [self.stringdelegate setsecond:inputString];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Comment: why u have created object for     TextviewExampleAppDelegate *check;  create the object for second class in which you are creating the object.

Comment: @coolanikothari can u help me what i have to do try as par ur ans but i not any solution please help me out

Answer (score 4):

1. remove delegate methods.
2. import your second class to first one.
3. in 2nd class import first class and implement `id firstClass` variable there.
4. when you pushing 2nd class, set `id` from (3) to self.
5. when you'v done and ready to pass it, set `firstClass.passedValue = passingValue`
6. pop second class

for example:

```
//first.h:
#import "second.h"
@class second

//second.h:
#import "first.h"
@class first
...
id firstClass;

//first.m:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    second *viewtwo =[[second alloc]initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewtwo animated:YES];
    viewtwo.firstClass = self;
    [viewtwo release];
}

//second.m:
firstClass.passedValue = self.passingValue;
```

Comment: can u give some example on it i try but my issue is not solve yet please help me on it

Comment: sentinel i done as par ur ans already done which u give but it not working my data not passing from second to first class

Comment: any errors? what exacally is in `passedValue` after this actions?

Comment: sentinel it not giving any error but it not passing value on first view it run without error

Comment: what value do you trying to pass? do you have @property for it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5612/discussion-between-rocky-and-sentinel)

Answer (score 3):

Please refer following rough scratch:

**in application delegate .h**

**Create variable**

```
NSString *varStr;
```

**Assign Property**

```
@propery (nonatomic, retain) NSString *valStr;
```

**In delegate .m**

```
@synthesize varStr;
```

**initialize var**

```
varStr = [NSString strinWithFormat:@"Hi"];
```

**in First class**

**create delegate var;**

```
delegate class *var = (delegate class*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

**set value**

```
var.varStr =  [NSString strinWithFormat:@"First"];
```

**get value**

```
NSLog (@"%@",var.varStr);
```

**in Second class**

**create delegate var;**

```
delegate class *var = (delegate class*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

**set value**

```
var.varStr =  [NSString strinWithFormat:@"Second"];
```

**get value**

```
NSLog (@"%@",var.varStr);
```

Comment: `delegate class var = (delegate class)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` is  not working man!!!...what can i do?i wanted to try your method in my application

Comment: Actually i have done nothing....i just want to know how can i pass multiple string data from one controller to another.I have used your method but when i use `delegate class var = (delegate class)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` then it shows delegate undefined.May be i have ask you a stupid question but actually i have never used `sharedApplication`.So help me please