# How to pass latitude value to next view in iphone?

Tags: ios, uitableview, navigation

I have got response from services and I have got latitude value and I copied into an array.
Now I want to pass the array when I click the next views row.

I passed places earlier. In second view `UITableViewController` is there if I click the particular row then it should be printed the rows text value and particular text's latitude value.....?
Is this possible...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *myText=[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"his is selected lattidude value:%@",myText);}
```

Here I am printing the row's text with this I need to print the latitude value of each one....please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass value from one viewController to another in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382063/how-to-pass-value-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `SecondViewController` in .h file just

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
     NSString *strLatLong;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strLatLong;

@end
```

and in .m file just synthesize it like bellow..

```
@synthesize *strLatLong
```

and in your `FirstViewController` class just push with bellow code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *myText=[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"his is selected lattidude value:%@",myText);
    SecondViewController *objSecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    objSecondView.strLatLong = myText;
    [objSecondView.strLatLong retain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondView animated:YES];
    [objSecondView release];

}
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: print this text in SecondViewController's viewWillAppear method with this code then check its print text or not NSLog(@"his is selected lattidude value:%@", strLatLong);

Answer (score 5):

There are lot many way to pass data from one view to other view.

Best for you is like:

Just create one variable in your second view controller.

When you push navigation from current page just before assign your value to that variable.

now you can easily use that value in your second view.

Answer (score 1):

Create `@property` in second viewcontroller  class `.h` file

```
 @property (nonatomic ) NSString *StrName;
```

`@synthesize` in second viewcontroller  class `.m` file

```
@synthesize StrName;
```

after that in your current viewcontroller class

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //NSString *myText=[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 secondviewcontroller *ss=[[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];

ss.StrName=[places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self presentModalViewController:ss animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must create a variable in second class and define his property and on first class you use this property to send one value to next class you sed value like this

```
in first class you create a variable with property like this
```

@property(nonatomic ,strong) NSString *str;

and in first class when you create the object of second class then you send the value like this

```
SecondClass *secondClass=[[SecondClass alloc]init];
secondClass.str=@"value is here";
```

in this method you send value to next class 
i hope you understand ;-)